# Unity2D: Showing message whille Player is in collision with an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

if its not too much i need help with something very trivial which i dont know how to do. I have a script in place that that lets the player go to next scene if it collides with "Door" while having a "Key"

If the player collides with "Door" without having "Key" i want a message to show for the duration of collision, and the message disappears after the player moves away from "Door"

help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a little bit of the code you have at the moment? And what do you mean with a message, something in a UI?

Comment: sorry for not adding the code i have... 


if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Level 3") && key)
        {SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 3");}

the "key" is a boolean which turns into true when the "Key" is collected. They have been coded for, and are working correctly.

This loads the next scene when the player has collected the key, and collided with an an object tagged with "Level 3".. i want a message to show if they collide with "Level 3" without collecting the "Key" first.

Answer (score 0):

In the Player Mono Behavior class, you can add the following code:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    if(collision.collider.name == "Door"){
        Debug.Log("Collided with wall!");

        if(player is holding key){
            //do something
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: also use OnCollisionExit() to detect when the collision ends